# Docx File Word count including footnotes/endnotes

Tags: .net, ms-word, openxml-sdk, aspose.words

I need to get word count of docx file based on the statistics provided in the ms word
(Review->Word count)
[image: screenshot from msword]

Sor far I tried to use Aspose.Words and OpenXml in .Net.
Both these tools provide me word count using BuiltInProperties or ExtendedProperties.

OpenXML

```
var appPart = wordprocessingDocument.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart;
```

Aspose

```
var wordCountValue = document.BuiltInDocumentProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Words")?.Value;
```

However, In case the checkbox provided above is "unchecked", then footnotes/endnotes words are not counted by both these frameworks.

I need to make sure that footnotes/endnotes are always counted.
I can't count words myself based on extracted text, as it will not be easy to get closed match as compared to ms word count.
Is there any way I can get this count?
OR is there any way I can confirm if the checkbox provided in statistics is "checked" or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BuiltInDocumentProperties.Words](https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.properties/builtindocumentproperties/words/) actually returns the value read from the document. See `app.xml` in the DOCX document:

```xml
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties" xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
    <Template>Normal.dotm</Template>
    <TotalTime>1</TotalTime>
    <Pages>1</Pages>
    <Words>1</Words>
    <Characters>9</Characters>
    <Application>Microsoft Office Word</Application>
    <DocSecurity>0</DocSecurity>
    <Lines>1</Lines>
    <Paragraphs>1</Paragraphs>
    <ScaleCrop>false</ScaleCrop>
    <Company></Company>
    <LinksUpToDate>false</LinksUpToDate>
    <CharactersWithSpaces>9</CharactersWithSpaces>
    <SharedDoc>false</SharedDoc>
    <HyperlinksChanged>false</HyperlinksChanged>
    <AppVersion>16.0000</AppVersion>
</Properties>
```

If the document has been generated by some external tool, number of words in the document might not be calculated. Aspose.Words does not update words count unless you explicitly call [Document.UpdateWordCount](https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/document/updatewordcount/) method.

The mentioned checkbox value is stored in `settings.xml` as `<w:doNotIncludeSubdocsInStats/>` tag (if unchecked). Aspose.Words takes this flag in account when `Document.UpdateWordCount` method is called. But unfortunately, there is no public API to get or set this flag.

You can post a feature request in [Aspose.Words support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8) to add API for `DoNotIncludeSubdocsInStats` flag.